# Change color of input box text as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to change certain words as user types in input box on run time. Is there anyway to do this as when I use replace jQuery function it replaces the value but does not allow me to change css of it. Thanks

Here is what I have achieved so far

This is Javascript:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
    var oldString = 'john',
    newString = '<span id="newChrome">chrome</span>'
    $("#text-editor").val($("#text-editor").val().replace(RegExp(oldString,"gi"),newString));
});
```

This is HTML

```
<input id="text-editor" maxlength="200" width:200px; />
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain more? you want to change color of a certain word while user typing that? I see you want to replace a `<span>` instead of `john` string?! you CANT do this.

Comment: You can't put html content inside an input and style it

Comment: Use a textarea instead

Comment: no. is it possible to change it in textarea ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`contenteditable`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) div elements you can achieve what you are trying to implement in most of the modern browsers.

```js
$("#submit-button").click(function() {
  var oldString = 'john',
    newString = '<span class="newChrome">chrome</span>',
    regex = new RegExp(oldString, "gi"),
    value = $("#text-editor").html(),
    str = value.replace(regex, newString);
  $("#text-editor").html(str);
});
$("#text-editor").on('input',function(){
  $a = $(this).find('span')
  $a.filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() != 'john';
  }).removeClass('newChrome');
  $a.filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == 'chrome';
  }).addClass('newChrome');
});
```

```css
.newChrome{
  color: red;
}
#text-editor{
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="text-editor" maxlength="200" style="width:200px;"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what i wanted but that helped.

Comment: @SydAbdRehmanKazmi Yes. Not the best idea. Other solution is to use an input and div with a show hide alternating based on focus and clikc.

Comment: can you help me with another thing? even after i have typed Chrome its also keeps the same css for the next word also. how to remove it ?

Comment: Are the letters supposed to be red when `Chrome` is typed in then submitted? I'm using Chrome 48 PC and I don't see it...Nevermind typed 'john' and it turned into 'chrome` in red letters?

Comment: yeah right. but the latter words should not be in red.